# window in mobile not closing

Tags: javascript, android

I have a website with PHP-pages that are opened and closed by Javascript.
In Internet Explorer on a desktop-computer everything works well: pages that are opened by Javascript can also be closed by Javascript.
On my smartphone with Android however this doesn't work: pages opened by Javascript are not closed by Javascript. So I get a whole accumulation of opened pages that block the Phone when the number is 15.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: In the first file: <script type="text/javascript">window.open("Secondfile.php"); window.close();</script>. In the second file: <script type="text/javascript">window.open("Thirdfile.php"); window.close();</script>

Comment: window.open("Thirdfile.php"); should be url address. like window.open("domain.com/Thirdfile.php");

Comment: Thank you, Flakerimi! It works well now!

Comment: Accept it please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a file

```
window.open("Thirdfile.php");
```

you should call url address. like

```
window.open("domain.com/Thirdfile.php");
```